# How to download private track in soundcloud using api?

Tags: soundcloud

I would  like to download some track from Soundcloud. But this track is private.

I have private link:

```
https://soundcloud.com/d-o-d/dod-1001tracklists-exclusive-mix/s-Y0mzp/s-Y0mzp
```

And this Api link:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/268430098%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-Y0mzp&show_artwork=false&color=D6DCFE
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Its possible to download private tracks like this. Just like how SoundCloud web interface gets the stream. Use Web Console (`Ctrl+Shift+J for chrome, Ctrl+Shift+K for firefox`) and you can see the requests in `Network` tab.

`https://api.soundcloud.com/i1/tracks/268430098/streams?client_id=CLIENT_ID_HERE&secret_token=s-Y0mzp&app_version=1468603618`

This will give you json like:

```
{"http_mp3_128_url":"https://cf-media.sndcdn.com/vxZL8GpudXiv.128.mp3?....","preview_mp3_128_url":"https://ec-preview-media.sndcdn.com/preview/0/30/vxZL8GpudXiv.128.mp3?..."}
```

And you can get `http_mp3_128_url` here.

Comment: Thanks) But if I paste url from "http_mp3_128_url" I get error "Forbidden".

Comment: Make sure you access that url with the same IP that made the first request. That's the only reason i can think of.

Comment: For anyone else with the same issue, make sure that you replace any unicode encoded characters. In my case, `\u0026` needed to be changed to `&`

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't seem to work for privately listed tracks (where the artist gives you the URL directly).

Answer (score -2):

Use https://video-download.co and use Documents 5 if you’re doing it from your phone. I found this [here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/KanyeLeaks/comments/7iknbx/how_do_you_download_private_soundcloud_playlists/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.